# Trouble finding the level curves of $f(x,y)=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the level curves of $f(x,y) = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$ for $f(x,y) = {-1,0,1}$.

I can not find examples in Stewart Calculus for rational equations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}=k \implies x^2+y^2-\frac2kx=0 \implies \left(x-\frac1k\right)^2+y^2=\frac1{k^2}$$

which is a circle centered at $\left(\frac1k, 0\right)$ with radius $R=\frac1{|k|}$.

Comment: oh you completed the square?

Comment: @BenJenney Yes exactly!

Comment: That didn't occur to me! This problem has been driving me crazy! THANK YOU!

Comment: @BenJenney You are welcome! Bye

Comment: The rule is **always** complete the square!  It there's a square, complete it!

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates,

$$2r\cos\theta=lr^2$$ or

$$r=\frac2l\cos\theta.$$

This is a family of homothetic circles through the origin.

The case $l=0$ is degenerate as the axis $x=0$.

Comment: Does that mean f(x,y) = l and l=0 does not exist? I'm confused by the meaning of degenerate in this context.

Comment: @BenJenney: it is not a circle.